# Easiest way to store a single timestamp in appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am running a Python script on Google's AppEngine. The python script is very basic. Every time the script runs i need it to update a timestamp *SOMEWHERE* so i can record and keep track of when the script last ran. This will allow me to do logic based on when the last time the script ran, etc. At the end of the script i'll update the timestamp to the current time.

Using Google's NBD seems to be overkill for this but it also seems to be the only way to store ANY data in AppEngine. Is there a better/easier way to do what i want?

Comment: Why is it overkill. A single model with a single field and a named key.  You can't get much simpler. Also you get transactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really is very simple, and not overkill..  Anything else will be overkill in appengine - trying to use the low level API, GCS or storing it in some other service will all require more work and introduce levels of complexity and potential unreliability and will be slower.  In addition any mechanism that doesn't store/retrieve datetime objects as datetime objects (ie text file) means you will need to parse the string as a date, creating even more work.

Define it

```
class TimeStamp(ndb.Model):
    timestamp = ndb.DatetimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Create it.

```
TimeStamp(key_name="TIMESTAMP").put()
```

Update it without reading.

```
TimeStamp(key_name="TIMESTAMP").put()
```

Read it, then update.

```
ts = TimeStamp.get_by_id("TIMESTAMP")
ts.put()
```

Comment: same. An elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this, that i found, is to use memcache. It's super easy. Though it should probably be noted that memcache could be cleared at anytime, so NDB is probably a better solution.

Set the timestamp:

> memcache.set("timestamp", current_timestamp)

Then, to read the timestamp:

> memcache.get("timestamp")

Comment: Matt, yep memcache is another strategy.  Usually best used if you have high frequency updates, and if the information is important, writing out to the datastore.  AS you noted it can be expunged, and this can happen quickly even within a few minutes.  I don't believe it is a good way to "store" data that you need to rely on.